# Get page slug/id from position in menu

Tags: menus

I have created a menu area(?) for use in my theme. The pages have been added to the menu in a consistent order via

```
Appearance -> Menus
```

This menu structure is used in multiple deployments, but the actual page slugs will differ across deployments.

If I know the menu name, how many pages are in the menu and in what position, how can I find the URL/slug/ID of a page in a certain position in the menu?

Comment: How are you adding the pages to the menu? If you are doing that, you should already have the ID or slug and can get any other information leveraging that.

Comment: I would like to do it programmatically. The pages are added manually by the clients in the Admin menu (`appearance`->`menus`) so I do not know the slugs etc